# Is there a way to bulk insert new sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an Apps Script where I need to insert a lot of new tabs into the spreadsheet. Each time I insert a new tab it takes between 12s-14s to call Google's API, which is super slow.

So my question: can I insert multiple sheets in one go, rather than making individual calls for each new one that I want to insert? There's no `insertSheets()` method in the docs.

To clarify: I'm not asking how to insert multiple sheets *in general* (I'd use a `for` loop for that), but how to insert multiple sheets efficiently with the least possible number of calls to the API.

Comment: FWIW, Adding too many sheets is a sign that you're structuring your spreadsheet unwisely. A sheet for <insert whatever> is never a good idea. Rethink your data structure. (To answer your question, Google sheets api is the efficient way)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the [bulkUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to send [requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#Request)

Send to `POST [https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate``](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%7BspreadsheetId%7D:batchUpdate%60%60)

and in your body

```
{
  requests : [
    addSheet : { properties: {title : "Sheet 1"} },
    addSheet : { properties: {title : "Sheet 2"} }

  ]
}
```